# Get username with current email address from database

Tags: php, mysql

As a designer I'm not that skilled in PHP+MySQL. For one of our projects we created a 'reset password' function which emails a new password to the user. Due to feedback from our users we'd like to add the username in this email as well.

This is the code we are currently using:

```
class password {

private $newpassword;
private $passwordlength = 10;

function __construct() {
    $this->newpassword = $this->getRandomPassword($this->passwordlength);
}

// This function resets the password
function resetPassword($email) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                    SET password = '".md5($this->newpassword)."' 
                        WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'") 
                            or die(mysql_error());
    $this->sendNewPassword($email);
}


// Check if email is exists
function checkEmailAdress($email) {
    $correctemail = false;

    $queryEmail = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users 
                        WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'")
                            or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($queryEmail) == 1) {
        $correctemail = true;
    }
    return $correctemail;
}

// Send new password with email
function sendNewPassword($email) {

    $onderwerp = 'New password for ... ';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $bericht = '<div>
                    Your new password is: '.$this->newpassword.'
                </div>

                <div>
                    Your username is: USERNAME HERE.
                </div>

                '; 

    mail($email, $onderwerp, $bericht, $headers);
}

// Generate random password
function getRandomPassword($length) {
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = "";    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}

}
```

The username is stored in the table 'username'.

How do I retrieve the username and add this in the '$bericht' (message)

Comment: For encrypting passwords for storage, please consider using the `crypt` function, as md5 password hashes can be broken unless they are correctly salted.

Comment: Having separate class for `password` seems to be overkill and smells like a bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your function add this

```
function resetPassword($email) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                SET password = '".md5($this->newpassword)."' 
                    WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'") 
                        or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username as username FROM users 
                    WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'") 
                        or die(mysql_error());
    $my_res = mysql_result($result); 
    $username = $my_res[0]['username'];
    $this->sendNewPassword($email,$username);
}
```

and at your mail add like

```
$bericht = '<div>
                Dear User: '.$username.'
            </div>

             <div>
                Your new password is: '.$this->newpassword.'
            </div>

            <div>
                Your username is: USERNAME HERE.
            </div>

            ';
```

Comment: And you would really do yourself a favour using the PDO library instead of the deprecated, and insecure, mysql library.

Comment: Yes @SBI you are right ,iam also want to suggest him to avoid mysql depricated functions,instead mysqli_* funmctions or pdo statements

Comment: Hi Gautam3164,

Thanks for the quick reply.. but I'mt not retrieving anything now. 

"Dear User:
Your username is:
"

Comment: once print $result at that function and then acc retrive the username...I think there is prob

Comment: if you're going to send passwords in email, please force the user to change them when they login - email is [predominantly] an unencrypted medium, and passwords sent in email should only be temporary ones.

Comment: just print $result at resetPassword function

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not a programmer. I putted 'print' before $results but still nothing helps..

Comment: Hi Gautam3164, really sorry didn't saw your edit. It's not working yet =(

Comment: Hi Gautam3164, I'm getting no result. If i 'print' before $result I see resources ID 5 (and it's the correct ID) but not the username. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Try my edit...i forgotted to add mysql_result...just add this and try to check $username by printing

Comment: Bah, still not working (even after using the edit - edit :-)). "Dear User:
Your new password is: somepassword"

Comment: But finally i can say its not my fault,no one can give here detail and line by line code,you need to traceout the things....try to trace the ans,

Comment: Hi Gautam3164, I undertand what you mean. I'll go check everything first. Thanks for again for the help!